# Compare specific column from different files and print the one dont match

Tags: awk

Comparing column 4 in file1 with colunan 5 in file2, will like to print the ones that do not match ( need be printed only the values in columns compared ).

**file1**

```
111 435 123 aaaa    
111 435 123 bbbb    
111 435 123 cccc    
111 435 123 dddd    
111 435 123 adas
```

**file2**

```
dff 233 444 asd aaaa
dff 233 444 asd bbbb
dff 233 444 asd cccx
dff 233 444 asd ddda
dff 233 444 asd adas
```

**desired output**

```
cccc cccx
dddd ddda
```

Using this code i got the desired output

```
paste file file2 | awk '{ if($1 != $2)  print }'
```

How I can fix the below code to get exactly desired output

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !(($1) in a)' file1 file2
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have gone with the `paste | awk` solution you already had but since you specifically asked for the pure awk version:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$4; next} $5 != a[FNR]{print a[FNR], $5}' file1 file2
cccc cccx
dddd ddda
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's changed input adding following solution.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$NF]=$NF
  next
}
($NF in a){
  delete a[$NF]
  next
}
{
  print $NF
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i
  }
}
' file1 file2 | paste -sd' '
```

---

---

Could you please try following (written and tested with shown samples).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=$0
  next
}
($0 in a){
  delete a[$0]
  next
}
1
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i
  }
}
' file1 file2 | paste -sd' '
```